# Runtime input checker

Tags: c#, runtime, runtime-error

If trying to make a console application program in c# that checks type errors on runtime
e.g if i want user to enter 777.
but if user enters 7a , it should give an error straight away without waiting for the user to press enter. 
can someone suggest something ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add console to it,and the answer is basically Console.ReadKey...

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is check each character a user enters as they enter it. Have a look at the OnKeyPress() event method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Inside OnKeyPress() you may handle the error as you would like.